# How to use \hglue \hskip etc. for multiple lines?

Tags: tex-core, context

I seem to be missing some major TeX techniques, as I can't find the information anywhere...

The idea is to have a typed environment with multiple lines shifted 2cm to the left. I tried

```
\hskip 2cm Text\\ next line
```

and

```
\hglue 2cm Text\\ next line
```

As you can surely imagine, the second line is not shifted anymore. The only thing I can do so far, is to put the commands in the beginning of every line, which drives me crazy...
So what would be the correct usage of \hskip and \hglue in such case?

I am using ConTeXt mkiv and my code looks like this:

```
\starttext

  Some initial text
  \blank [big]

  \hglue 3cm
  The code to the graphic above looks like this:
  \starttyping
    content line 1
    content line 2
  \stoptyping

\stoptext
```

Comment: You're looking for `\leftskip`. But what it's called in ConTeXt, I don't know.

Comment: Hey thanks. As far as i know ConTeXt can handle plain TeX as well. In this case anyway it works.
But how can I stop the \leftskip "environment"?  I tried \unskip but this only deletes the following blank line vertically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `\start...\stopnarrower`.

```
\starttext

  Some initial text
  \blank [big]

  \setupnarrower[left=3cm]
  \startnarrower[left]
    The code to the graphic above looks like this:
    \starttyping
      content line 1
      content line 2
    \stoptyping
  \stopnarrower

\stoptext
```

Apparently `\start...\stopnarrow` (without `er`) is also available.

```
\starttext

  Some initial text
  \blank [big]

  \startnarrow[left=3cm][left]
    The code to the graphic above looks like this:
    \starttyping
      content line 1
      content line 2
    \stoptyping
  \stopnarrow

\stoptext
```

You can also use plain `\leftskip` wrapped in a `\start...\stop` group.

```
\starttext

  Some initial text
  \blank [big]

  \start\leftskip=3cm
    The code to the graphic above looks like this:
    \starttyping
      content line 1
      content line 2
    \stoptyping
  \stop

  No leftskip

\stoptext
```

Comment: Thank you very much Henri. I think this is how it should be used in ConTeXt. I will stick to this in the future, but it's also good to know the plain TeX equivalent as user egreg describes it further above.

Comment: @Koenich Plain equivalent added.

Comment: Thanks a lot Henri. Both ways (CTX and TeX) are exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know two additional things that you just shared with me.
First that you can also use \leftskip=3cm
(I didn't know that the equal sign can be used directly after a TeX command in CTX.)
Second that you can use \start \stop groups like this.
That's why I love ConTeXt.

Comment: I just figured that the method of using the equal sign between a TeX command and the argument doesn't work that easy.

While indeed it works with
    \leftskip=3cm
It doesn't work with
    \hglue=3cm
as you will get a "missing number"-error.

Only for the record. :)

Comment: @Koenich Of course it doesn't work.  `\leftskip` is a register which can be assigned, whereas `\hglue` is a command which expects a number.